# how to reorder the div on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

how to reorder the div elements on each time the page refresh?
for example-

```
<div class="class1"><a href="1.html">first</a></div>
<div class="class2"><a href="1.html">second</a></div>
<div class="class3"><a href="1.html">third</a></div>
```

i want to see reodering on page refresh like ..now the current order is 1-2-3
when i refresh it will become 2-3-1..
so each time the page refresh it will change its position of div?

Comment: Are you going to do it in php or javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tagged front and backend langauges, here's a PHP solution: just put all your elements into an array and [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) them:

If your divs are more complex, put the entire output in a variable and add that variable to the array. Or if they're simple (like your example) but require a bit more information, use an associative array and [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

```
$array = array(
    'first'  => array( 'class' => 'foo', 'href' => 'bar.html' ),
    'second' => array( 'class' => 'john', 'href' => 'doe.html' ),
    'third'  => array( 'class' => 'x', 'href' => 'y.html' ),
);

uksort( $array, function() { return rand() > rand(); } ); //This will mix them up.

foreach( $array as $item => $atts ){
    echo '<div class="'. $atts['class'] .'"><a href="'. $atts['href'] .'">'. $item .'</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: fatal error? Cannot use empty array elements in arrays in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 3

Comment: I had an extra comma after the `second` element, removing that you can see if functions in that sandbox

Comment: please share me the exact codes which all work sir! please

Comment: Oh I apologize, I accidentally mixed up my two arrays and forgot to update the second one. Here you go: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/294fca5406943bde8812cdd626c41f4ce02bf638

Comment: use `shuffle` for a simple array, or `uksort` for an associative one

Comment: thank you sir!  it is working thnks again..

Answer (score 0):

On the Javascript side: put all of the divs into a container, then:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const children = [...container.children];
children.forEach(child => child.remove());
const randomChildren = children.map((child) => ({ child, rand: Math.random() }));
randomChildren.sort((a, b) => b.rand - a.rand);
randomChildren.forEach(randomObj => container.appendChild(randomObj.child));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using JavaScript with array shuffle

```
function shuffle(arra1) {
        var ctr = arra1.length,
            temp, index;
        while (ctr > 0) {
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
            ctr--;
            temp = arra1[ctr];
            arra1[ctr] = arra1[index];
            arra1[index] = temp;
        }
        return arra1;
    }
    var myArray = [
        '<div class="class1"><a href="1.html">first</a></div>',
        '<div class="class2"><a href="1.html">second</a></div>',
        '<div class="class3"><a href="1.html">third</a></div>'
    ];

    var randomHtml = shuffle(myArray).join("");
    document.getElementById("some").innerHTML = randomHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following script. It will shuffle divs on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

var arr = ['<div class="class1"><a href="1.html">first</a></div>', '<div class="class2"><a href="1.html">second</a></div>', '<div class="class3"><a href="1.html">third</a></div>'];
arr = shuffle(arr);
arr.map(function (k,v){
$(".div-wrap").append(k);
});
});
```

In your html just add one div

```
<div class="div-wrap">

</div>
```

Here is a working example...

https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/2hhsaLh9/6/

Comment: how do it in a php?